# How to simplify checking if a pair of numbers is (1,2) or (2,1)?

Tags: c++, c, logic

I need to make sure that a pair of numbers is either (1, 2) or (2, 1). Both x and y are always positive. The code I am using right now:

```cpp
if ((x == 2 && y == 1) ||
    (x == 1 && y == 2)) {
    return 1;
}
```

It looks a little bulky, and I feel like it can be simplified. However, everything I tried resulted in false positives.

Comment: You could multiply them, the result being 2 or not 2.  That reduces source code size by a few chars at the expense of everything else.  Just go with the easy to understand, easy to debug.

Comment: @MartinJames To be fair, I think the OP is asking for simpler code, not for a code golfed solution. Also, your solution would fail for `-1` and `-2`.

Comment: @cigien umm... 'Both x and y are always positive'

Comment: @MartinJames Oh, good point, I missed that :p You could write a solution then, though it may not be simpler to read.

Comment: @cigien 'You could write a solution' no thanks - feel free to post it if you want:)  I prize clarity, and so ease of debugging, over 'clever' tricks:)

Comment: Assuming `x` and `y` are both of an integral type AND other code ensures they are both positive, then the statement can be simplified to `if (x * y == 2)`.     This will not work as intended if `x` and `y` can hold values that (in combination) cause the multiplication to overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the most direct way to make this comparison.

It is also more readable than any alternative you may come up with, so no need to change it.

Comment: I'm down-voting this answer because it's making a strong claim without any evidence. Not being able to imagine a simpler, or more readable solution is not really an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to write it that I think is more readable:

```
if (std::set{x,y} == std::set{1,2})
{
    return 1;
}
```

Note that this is not as efficient as the version in your question. Don't write this in code that you're going to ship as a library, for example. But this is perfectly reasonable to write in your own programs when performance is not a concern.

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3YWY16).

Comment: This is a horribly expensive piece of code. This answer really should be labeled “just kidding”.

Comment: @PeteBecker It is expensive, but the OP has not indicated that performance is a concern for them. And I'm not kidding at all, I do think this is readable code that expresses the intent "check if two things are 1 and 2" more clearly. I've edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: @cigien — spoken like a true Python programmer. <g>

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see you simplify it will be having a struct to represent you `x` and `y`, if this is some kind of coordinate, you could use something like `vector2d` or `std::pair<int, int>`

Then you could do :

```
    std::pair<int, int> valuePair = std::make_pair(x, y);
    if (valuePair == std::make_pair(1, 2) || valuePair == std::make_pair(2, 1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: This *may* be in improvement in a language like Python (`(x, y) in {(1, 2), (2, 1)}`), but in C++, that's far too verbose to be of a benefit.

Comment: I think it depends, as a game programmer, I prefer to compare the `vector` as a whole struct instead of doing it per component. Of course in that case I will not be using `std::pair` but `vector2d` instead.

Comment: As another game programmer I prefer it as written since we are given no other context. If it was already a vector or some other type then comparing that way is fine, but if not I don't see a need to force it into something it is not. Your example is also incomplete as it does not actually put the values into `valuePair`.

Comment: I'll note that I haven't downvoted. I was just giving an opinion about why you may have been. But ya, if you already have pre-defined pairs, comparing them directly will be cleaner than "deconstructing" them and comparing the pieces. I'm not sure it's cleaner if you're starting with pieces though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah, agree, it's context-dependent. :)
This is why I put, `If this is some kind of coordinate`

Answer (score -1):

Can the values be 0? Some say 0 is not positive or negative.

If X and Y are both > 0, then how about:

```
if( 3 == (x + y) ) { return 1; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might (ab)use `std::minmax`:

```
if (std::minmax(x, y) == std::pair<const int&, const int&>{1, 2})
{
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
if (std::minmax(x, y) == std::minmax(1, 2))
{
    return 1;
}
```

or (C++17)

```cpp
if (auto [a, b] = std::minmax(x, y); a == 1 && b == 2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is less readable in every way. I see no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: @CodyGray: I was expecting `std::minmax(x, y) == {1, 2}` but types mismatch.